# inserting unique primary key exception

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying to insert records to a table using statement like

```
insert into table
(table_id, xxx,xxx)
values
(100,xxx,xxx)
```

and get the unique violation on the primary key.
and i did a select

```
select * from table where table_id = 100;
```

There is no record there.Thought insert before then, delete record.

And if i dont insert the table id, i got a null violation.

I was wondering if there is anyway to deal with this(maybe sequence)? I need to insert several thousands records using the inserting statement. some hundered have this prob.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: More details: i have a program to generate the inserting statement. I prefer to do inserting this way(instead of in a loop with function or procedure)

Comment: Is the `table_id` and auto numbered field?

Comment: yeah, table_id  is a numbered field. not knowing if it is auto-increment field.

Comment: If it is an autonumbered field then don't supply it in the insert statement:`insert into table (xxx, xxx) values (xxx, xxx)`

Comment: How is the primary key defined?  Are there any other unique indexes/constraints on the table?

Comment: just chked, it is not a auto field.

Comment: i got the exception on the primary key, table_id is the primary key. i dont think other constraints matters in this situation

Comment: So you are inserting into a table and you are supplying the primarykey value. Where do you get the value from? Remember that if you are inserting more than 1 row in a single statement and 2 or more rows have the same value for the primary key you will see this exception but there will not be a row with that value afterwards. This is because the entire insert would be rolled back. If you can provide a bit more detail about what your table looks like and what your inserts statements are we can probably help. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: I think i got what my prob is! there is another composite unique key i violate, not the primary key. But from you guys i just realize that maybe providing the primary key is risky. Will modify my program a little. Thanks!